# How to scrape the response of the files that appear in the Network tab in the Inspect element of a website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvRle.png) is a screenshot of the response I am trying to scrape. I am trying to scrape the response that is received on **restaurant** file (document type). I am trying to scrape using `selenium` and Python.

I tried different ways to scrape it but couldn't find a particular way.
I tried using `desired_capabilities` to get the logs:

```
desired_capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
```

The closest I can get to extracting the info about the restaurant response is in the code below, which prints out the info about the restaurant file. However, still I am unable to get the response of the document.

I am trying to scrape [this website](https://food.grab.com/ph/en/restaurants).

```
import time
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

# make chrome log requests

def get_actions(driver):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    return actions

def setup():
    desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    desired_capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities, executable_path=r"C:\Users\visha\PycharmProjects\grabScrapper\chromedriver.exe"
    )

    address = 'Manila '
    driver.get('https://food.grab.com/ph/en/restaurants')
    time.sleep(2)  # Let the user actually see something!
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("textPlaceholder___1yEAK").click()

    actions = get_actions(driver)
    actions.send_keys(address)
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(1)

    actions = get_actions(driver)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(1)

    actions = get_actions(driver)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)

    logs = driver.get_log("performance")

    print(json.loads(logs[0]["message"])["message"])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = setup()
```

Here is the output:

```
{'method': 'Network.requestWillBeSent', 'params': {'documentURL': 
'https://food.grab.com/ph/en/restaurants', 'frameId': '511A291FBAE6A23A8A6CC0151F478245',         
'hasUserGesture': False, 'initiator': {'type': 'other'}, 'loaderId': 
'398F451EBDC9243DC9A05E18809AD020', 'request': {'headers': {'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36', 'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A 
Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"', 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 'sec-ch-ua-platform': 
'"Windows"'}, 'initialPriority': 'VeryHigh', 'isSameSite': True, 'method': 'GET', 
'mixedContentType': 'none', 'referrerPolicy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'url': 
'https://food.grab.com/ph/en/restaurants'}, 'requestId': '398F451EBDC9243DC9A05E18809AD020', 
'timestamp': 75113.949225, 'type': 'Document', 'wallTime': 1632732378.366389}}
```

Please help me to scrape the response data of the restaurant file using Python so that I can do some manipulation on my own.